# Any possible way to save output of sqlplus command into an array - Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, sqlplus, spool

Currently, I am spooling the sqlplus command into a text file but even this is causing me problems as I would like to separate the values by commas. So far It has not worked.

I was hoping something like this would work

```
 @test = system('sqlplus un/pw@host @test.sql');
```

The test.sql file contains three statements all returning numbers. If I could save these to the @test array, this would be great.

Any ideas?

Comment: `system` does not return standard output, it returns the return value of the system call. To capture output use backticks or `qx()`, but you will need to escape the `@` characters to avoid interpolation. However, if you are querying a database, you might be better off using the DBI module.

Comment: check this:http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2013/01/list-of-columns-in-table-from-sybase.html .where in here it uses sybase just remove the sybase part and put sqlplus instead of isql.the remaining it stores each line of the result into an array.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [DBI](http://p3rl.org/DBI) module with [DBD::Oracle](http://p3rl.org/DBD%3a%3aOracle):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use DBI;

my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:Oracle:host=host;sid=dbname",
                       $user, $password);

open my $IN, '<', 'test.sql' or die $!;
$/ = ';'; # Queries separated by semicolons, no other semicolons anywhere!
while (my $sql = <$IN>) {
    my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $sth->execute;
    my @test = @{ $sth->fetchall_arrayref // [] };
    print "@$_\n" for @test;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The DBI script based is good, but if your point is about the use of sqlplus command in any case, you should take a look at this CPAN module: [Expect](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Expect.pm). It provides you a deeper control of an external command in many and useful ways.